# PostGIS - Error when converting shapefile into dataset using openJUMP

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, openjump

[image: SQL Exception]

I am new to this field. I want to save my shapefile as a dataset in PostGIS using openJUMP, but I'm getting an error. Can anybody suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Which OpenJUMP and PostGIS versions?

Comment: OpenJUMP1.7.1 and PostGIS 2.1.3

Comment: now am tried postgis import/export manager...can't import shp file into postgis...its also same error...

Comment: Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 25: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','chennai','geom','0','MULT...
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: What do you get with select postgis_version();

Comment: now i solved this problem...i didnt give extension of postgis.

Comment: now i solved this problem...i didnt give extension of postgis. after add postgis extension its working. Thanks user30184

Answer (score 2):

The OpenJUMP error message resends the error from PostgreSQL database. The message tells that AddGeometryColumn function does not exist and that indicates that the GIS database is missing PostGIS. PostGIS extension is not installed automatically to new databases but it must be explicitly installed by using SQL

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```